# Using ENC28J60 on /dev/spidev1.0 or /dev/spidev1.2

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, spi, pi-3a+

I'm forced to use port `/dev/spidev0.0` with a camera that I'm not able to configure at this time. Hence I need to change my current configuration where I'm using **ENC28J60** on `/dev/spidev0.0` and move it on a different port:  `/dev/spidev1.0` or `/dev/spidev1.2` (`spidev1.1/CE` pin is used as an interrupt source from the camera itself). I googled for info but the only useful reference is this thread on RPi forum:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191180

that talks only about changing `CE` pin in terms of redefining (?) the overlay that's something I'm not proficient in. Someone managed to use a different port for **ENC28J60** and can guide me in this process?

BTW I'm using *Raspbian 9* (stretch) on a **RPi3A+** (I would like to make it work on **RPi0W** also if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following *joan* hint I found a possibile solution into making a new `.dts` (`enc28j60-spi1-overlay`):

```
// Overlay for the Microchip ENC28J60 Ethernet Controller - SPI1
// Interrupt pin: 25
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&spi1>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            status = "okay";

            eth1: enc28j60@0{
                compatible = "microchip,enc28j60";
                reg = <0>; /* CE0 */
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&eth1_pins>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                interrupts = <25 0x2>; /* falling edge */
                spi-max-frequency = <12000000>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            eth1_pins: eth1_pins {
                brcm,pins = <25>;
                brcm,function = <0>; /* in */
                brcm,pull = <0>; /* none */
            };
        };
    };

    __overrides__ {
        int_pin = <&eth1>, "interrupts:0",
                  <&eth1_pins>, "brcm,pins:0";
        speed   = <&eth1>, "spi-max-frequency:0";
    };
};
```

And compiling it with:

```
sudo dtc -I dts -O dtb -o /boot/overlays/enc28j60-sp1.dtbo enc28j60-spi1-overlay.dts
```

And finally *enabling* it in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtparam=spi=on          #enable spi
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs      #enable spi1 (and CE0, CE1)
dtoverlay=enc28j60-spi1 #enable enc28j60 module on spi1 port
```

I tested it on my LAN and it seems to works fine (not worse than using default `spi0` port).

I found a pretty similar solution here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224915

You can use it also but beware it assign by default **enc28j60** interrupt to pin **39** and this will not work on standard **RPi** boards (such pin is *user* availabe only on Compute Module).

Comment: Works great. Thank you. If I could give 10 upvotes I would.

Comment: one upvote is more than enogh.

Comment: Great work @weirdgyn , I have a followup question <https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/139936/114130>
I wanted to both spi0 and spi1 to be enabled parallely as 2 ethernet port is required. I have tried but not seeing success. Kudos.

Comment: @HarishPatil I don't know if I can be of any help .. in my solution I needed to switch from the *standard* configuration to an alternative using different port/pin mappings ... in your case you wish to *run* multiple copies of the enc28j60 driver. IMHO this may work or not work but it depends on the driver structure itself not the configuration

Comment: @weirdgyn after some research I am thinking why cant I use spi1 on enc2860 module and spi0 for wiznet w5500 module, thats a separate kernel driver. So i started making enc2860 on spi, but not with good success. I Just wanted to understand which pin you have used in as interrupt pin 39 mentioned above. If you write some answer with pin diagram It would be worth lot upvotes.

Comment: @Noel can you help me with above comment, about pin diagram or any thing missing in the above answer. I am not able to make enc2860 work on spi1.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from `/boot/overlays/README` you need to add the following entry in `/boot/config.txt` (and remove or comment out any existing enc28j60 entry).

`dtoverlay=enc28j60-spi2`

From your forum link that should use chip enable 0.

The relevant part of the README is:

```
Name:   enc28j60-spi2
Info:   Overlay for the Microchip ENC28J60 Ethernet Controller on SPI2
Load:   dtoverlay=enc28j60-spi2,<param>=<val>
Params: int_pin                 GPIO used for INT (default 39)

        speed                   SPI bus speed (default 12000000)
```

Comment: Wow! Thnx. Hope it works.. I'll let you know.

Comment: What GPIO pins is 39? It's not a big problem since it can be changed but RPI has not 39 GPIO pins and pin 39 is a GND pin ...

Comment: another question... which spi is spi2? in all the docs I've looked into I found only reference of spi0 and spi1.

Comment: uhm looks like `spi2` is only available on compute module not in standard **RPi**.

Comment: Pi actually has GPIO 0-53.  Most Pis only have GPIO 0-27 connected to the outside of the board.

Comment: it's not a big problem anyway since `spi2` is not available on standard **RPi** boards it looks like the only option is to write a custom `.dts` (to manage something like `enc28j60-spi1`) and try... but I need to undestand how to do this...