# Enable ENC28J60 on Raspberry Pi 4 SPI1 CE1

Tags: spi, driver

I have a Raspberry Pi model 4B V1.4 running:

> Linux raspberrypi 5.10.42-v7l+ #1422 SMP Tue Jun 8 13:03:05 BST 2021
> armv7l GNU/Linux

I want to connect an ENC28J60 spi ethernet adapter on spi1. Using SPI1_CE1 and interrupt on GPIO5.

I have tried to follow the instructions given here, but modified for my hardware setup:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/104911/106761

First I copied the enc28j60 overlay file for spi2 from here:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/enc28j60-spi2-overlay.dts

Then changed the contents to match my settings:

```
// Overlay for the Microchip ENC28J60 Ethernet Controller
// Interrupt pin: 39
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

        fragment@0 {
                target = <&spi1>;
                __overlay__ {
                        /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        status = "okay";

                        eth1: enc28j60@0{
                                compatible = "microchip,enc28j60";
                                reg = <1>; /* CE1 */
                                pinctrl-names = "default";
                                pinctrl-0 = <&eth1_pins>;
                                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                                interrupts = <39 0x2>; /* falling edge */
                                spi-max-frequency = <12000000>;
                                status = "okay";
                        };
                };
        };

        fragment@1 {
                target = <&gpio>;
                __overlay__ {
                        eth1_pins: eth1_pins {
                                brcm,pins = <39>;
                                brcm,function = <0>; /* in */
                                brcm,pull = <0>; /* none */
                        };
                };
        };

        __overrides__ {
                int_pin = <&eth1>, "interrupts:0",
                          <&eth1_pins>, "brcm,pins:0";
                speed   = <&eth1>, "spi-max-frequency:0";
        };
};
```

Then to use the overlay file I compiled and moved it with the command:

```
sudo dtc -I dts -O dtb -o /boot/overlays/enc28j60-spi1.dtbo enc28j60-spi1-overlay.dts
```

Then added the following to /boot/config.txt:

```
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=enc28j60-spi1,int_pin=5
#gpio=17=a4
```

After a reboot I get then try to verify that the gpio signals are correct with the command:

```
raspi-gpio get 17; raspi-gpio get 19-21; raspi-gpio get 5
GPIO 17: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 19: level=0 fsel=3 alt=4 func=SPI1_MISO pull=DOWN
GPIO 20: level=0 fsel=3 alt=4 func=SPI1_MOSI pull=DOWN
GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=3 alt=4 func=SPI1_SCLK pull=DOWN
GPIO 5: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
```

I expected GPIO17 to be alt4 here and have tested adding, "gpio=17=a4" to /boot/config.txt. When I then try the command

```
raspi-gpio get 17
```

I get the expected result

```
GPIO 17: level=1 fsel=3 alt=4 func=SPI1_CE1_N pull=DOWN
```

However that still does not work. I have also tried to debug with the following command:

```
sudo vcdbg log msg
```

which produces the following output:

```
007284.630: dtb_file 'bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb'
007290.276: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
007290.293: Loading 'bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb' to 0x100 size 0xc042
007302.977: brfs: File read: 49218 bytes
007314.358: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/overlay_map.dtb
007377.407: brfs: File read: 1559 bytes
007379.606: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
007380.007: dtparam: i2c_arm=on
007388.563: brfs: File read: 1862 bytes
007399.241: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/spi1-1cs.dtbo
007408.278: Loaded overlay 'spi1-1cs'
007408.299: dtparam: spi=on
007448.156: brfs: File read: 1523 bytes
007461.603: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/enc28j60-spi1.dtbo
007468.085: Loaded overlay 'enc28j60-spi1'
007468.096: dtparam: int_pin=5
007468.572: dtparam: audio=on
007498.567: brfs: File read: 1148 bytes
007511.775: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/vc4-fkms-v3d.dtbo
007529.231: Loaded overlay 'vc4-fkms-v3d'
007569.087: brfs: File read: 1446 bytes
007570.709: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/cmdline.txt
007570.752: Read command line from file 'cmdline.txt':
007570.767: 'console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=af4c75fe-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles'
008648.405: brfs: File read: 143 bytes
009243.785: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/kernel7l.img
009243.806: Loading 'kernel7l.img' to 0x8000 size 0x675a48
009243.830: Device tree loaded to 0x2eff3800 (size 0xc76c)
009249.694: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin SDCARD_CONTROL_POWER not defined
012642.554: vchiq_core: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xded80000, is_master = 1
016247.739: brfs: File read: 6773320 bytes
```

If i type "ifconfig" there is no eth1 available. Someone mentioned that it was necessary to remove console=tty1 from "/boot/cmdline.txt". Which I have also tried but no luck.

I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with this board: https://wiki.52pi.com/index.php/Pi_Zero_Enc28j60_Network_Adapter_Module_SKU:_EP-0088 which also uses ENC28J60. Mine had jumper pins connected incorrectly. I could not see eth device. I reconnected them as per images on board wiki. That solved the issue.